# Writing a Gson TypeAdapter for a class that has its own implementation of JSON Serialization

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson

I am trying to serialize a class where one of the members comes with its own implementation of JSON Serialization. I'm not sure how to include it with the rest of the properties.
For example

```
class Foo {
    String fieldA;
    String fieldB;
    Bar bar;
}
```

class `Bar` has a method `toJSONString()`. Currently I am including it by registering a `JsonSerializer` as  `TypeAdapter`  something like :

```
class BarSerializer implements JsonSerializer<Bar> {
   @Override
   public JsonElement serialize(Bar bar, Type type, JsonSerializationContext ctxt) {
       return new JsonParser().parse(bar.toJSONString());
   }
```

}

I cannot change the code of `Bar` or I cannot serialize it using its fields directly as it has some deeply nested structure and I don't have any control over its member class types. As you can see in the above method the `Bar` object is serialized, parsed and serialized again.
Is there any other simple/efficient way of serializing `Bar` within `Foo`?

Answer (score 1):

If you want an efficient way, it is suggested to use [TypeAdapter](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/TypeAdapter.html)

Below explanation is copied from [JsonSerializer](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonSerializer.html)'s document:

> New applications should prefer TypeAdapter, whose streaming API is
>   more efficient than this interface's tree API.

Check out this [link](http://www.javacreed.com/gson-typeadapter-example/) for some good examples about TypeAdapter.